# Удаление папок названия которых начинаются со строки

Tags: linux, unix

Есть список папок:

```
2014-12-17
2014-12-21
2014-12-22
2014-12-23
2015-01-13
2015-01-14
2015-01-15
2015-01-16
2015-01-17
```

Как удалить все папки и их содержимое, названия которых начинаются с "2014"?
Спасибо.

Comment: `rm 2014* -rf`, но только аккуратно

Comment: что значит "аккуратно"?)

Comment: ну, можно добавить один пробел и получить проблем.  `rm 2014 * -rf` - удалит немного больше.

Comment: @mee когда набираете команду `rm -rf что_нибудь` всегда стоит минимум 2 раза подумать, что именно эта команда удалит, прежде, чем жмакнуть <Enter>.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

как написано в `man bash`, раздел *EXPANSION*, подраздел *Pathname Expansion*, подзаголовок *Pattern Matching*, символ <kbd>*</kbd> может быть использован вместо любого количества символов при обращении к файлам/каталогам.

в приложении к вашему вопросу «маска» `2014*` «отберёт» только те файлы/каталоги, имя которых содержит `2014` и далее *любое количество символов*:

```
$ ls -d 2014*
2014-12-17
2014-12-21
2014-12-22
2014-12-23
```

а для удаления (непустых) каталогов следует использовать команду `rm -r имя-каталога`:

```
$ rm -r 2014*
```

Comment: rm -r 2014*
rm: спуститься в каталог «2014-12-17»? Так пишет.

Comment: @mee, дело происходит в дистрибутиве ubuntu? там, насколько я знаю, *rm* является псевдонимом (*alias*) для *rm -i* (см. в `man rm`, что это значит) — «забота о пользователе, чтобы не поранился». чтобы избежать использования псевдонима при запуске, можно добавить обратный слэш перед `rm`: `\rm -r 2014*`.